# How to show that $f(x) = x|x|$ is differentiable at 0?

Tags: functions, derivatives

So I've gotten $$f'(x)=\dfrac{2x^2}{|x|}$$

How to show that the following function is differentiable at 0?

Comment: Forget the formulas, use the definition.

Comment: I'm surprised to see darya's answer accepted. In spite of the fact that there's nothing wrong with it, (the existence and equality of the lateral limits of the derivative does imply the existence of the derivative), the proof of this fact is unlikely to have been presented to you before this problem and the proof itself is harder than just using the definition like Timbuc did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x|x|=\begin{cases}
 & \text{ if } x \succeq 0  :y=x^2 \\ 
 & \text{ if } x <0    :y=-x^2
\end{cases}
$$
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
 & \text{ if } x > 0  :y=2x \\ 
 & \text{ if } x <0    :y=-2x
\end{cases} 
$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow  0^{-}}f'(x)=0\\\lim_{x\rightarrow  0^{+}}f'(x)=0
$$ so  f(x) is  differentiable at 0

Comment: I think there should be some extra details like: $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, so by L'Hôpital's rule, $\lim_{x\to  0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to  0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: prove the defining limit exists

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x|x|-0}x=\ldots$$

Comment: No, the expression does *not* equal $\;x\;$ but rather $\;|x|\;$ .

Comment: But $|0|=0$, isn't it?

Comment: That's another matter, and yes.

Comment: But why in the world you write that nonsensical equality on the left *again* ?! It must be $\;\frac{x|x|-o}x=\frac{x|x|}x=|x|\;$ ...!

Comment: @Marc, no...$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x|x|}x=\lim_{x\to 0}|x|=0$$